# How to clean IsolatedStorageSettings on new version application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

It is possible to clean `IsolatedStorageSettings` when application updates to new version ?
Thanks.

Comment: What part of "clean IsolatedStorageSettings when application update[s]" you can't handle? "clean IsolatedStorageSettings" or "when application update[s]"?

Comment: Perhaps you could store the last known version there and compare on application load?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the [IsolatedStorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay840d1%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.